# Metacontroller: how to stop calls to sync hooks and resource generation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

I'm using [Metacontroller](https://metacontroller.app) to implement a Kubernetes operator.

My problem is the following:

1. Metacontroller never stops calling my sync hook for my controller ( [composite controllers](https://metacontroller.app/api/compositecontroller/) in that case), and
2. the parent resources `status.observedGeneration` field is getting updated continuously (from what I understand that means the resource was recreated).

The composite controller documentation (specifically the [response documentation](https://metacontroller.app/api/compositecontroller/#sync-hook-response)) suggests that if there are no changes in the returned parent status or in the children collection, Metacontroller should stop calling the sync hook.

I additionally removed `spec.resyncPeriodSeconds` and `spec.parentResource.revisionHistory` from the composite controller manifest (to not trigger any calls to the sync hook due to timer events or changes to the parent's `status` field) .

Sadly, none of this worked. How can I tell Metacontroller to stop calling the sync hook and stop to create the resource?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to enable the "status" subresource for your CRD: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#status-subresource

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: myresource
spec:
...
  subresources:
    status: {}
```

Without that, Metacontroller will treat status updates as normal resource updates which in turn creates a new `.metadata.resourceVersion` / `.metadata.generation` because Metacontroller always adds an updated `.status.observedGeneration` field.

See here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/metacontroller/blob/985572b9052a306f7e4d4fb84f2ced6f74247dd5/dynamic/clientset/clientset.go#L200

I have created an issue for this: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/metacontroller/issues/176

Hopefully this will make this situation more obvious in the future.